# Make Visual Studio minify css and js on publish\compile

Tags: visual-studio-2013, minify

I have a project that works that works as a subapplication on a site (actually multiple sites). Among other things, I have several static css and js files in this project. I need to keep those as separate js and css files, but to keep google happy, I'd like to minify those. Those files are likely to be modified in the future, so I'd like to avoid manually minifying them every time they are changed.

Is there some option that would allow me to minify those files on compile or publish (other than writing build events to minify those files using external tools).

Answer (score 4):

The following pertains to VS2015, which has much better support for this scenario.

VS2015 introduces support for task runners like gulp or grunt.  You could use one of those, and have a task triggered on project open (i.e. always runs while you're working on the project) which will itself monitor for file changes and run the minimizer (i.e. do it on save).

An intro to gulp in VS2015 is available [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-gulp.html).

A simpler alternative on VS2015 is to use the [Web Compiler Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c), which basically does the above automagically with less work on your side to set it up.

Comment: That's good to know, but right now I'm working on a VS2013 project and migration is out of question.

Comment: @jahu did you find any?

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki At first I used yuicompressor, but that didn't work on coworker's computer, because he didn't have Java installed. In the end I just used bundling from `System.Web.Optimization`.

Answer (score 4):

All solutions I found required using different filenames for the minimized versions, and a lot of extra work to switch between using the normal/minified versions.

Instead, I wanted the compressed JavaScript files to have the original names so I didn't have to change the references in my HTML markup. I could use the normal Javascript files in my development environment, then minimized versions would be automatically deployed when publishing.

I found a simple solution that does just that.

First, install [Microsoft Ajax Minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/).

Then, in your Visual Studio project file, just before the closing `</Project>` tag add the following :

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\Microsoft Ajax Minifier\ajaxmin.tasks" />
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(ConfigurationName)'=='Release'">
  <ItemGroup>
    <JS Include="**\*.js" Exclude="**\*.min.js;obj\**\*.*" />
  <CSS Include="**\*.css" Exclude="**\*.min.css;obj\**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <AjaxMin
    JsSourceFiles="@(JS)" JsSourceExtensionPattern="\.js$" JsTargetExtension=".jsMIN"
    CssSourceFiles="@(CSS)" CssSourceExtensionPattern="\.css$" CssTargetExtension=".cssMIN" />
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
  <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    CustomCollectFiles;
    $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
  </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MinJS Include="**\*.jsMIN" />
    <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(MinJS.Identity)">
      <DestinationRelativePath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename).js</DestinationRelativePath>
    </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    <MinCSS Include="**\*.cssMIN" />
    <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(MinCSS.Identity)">
      <DestinationRelativePath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename).css</DestinationRelativePath>
    </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

What does the above code do? When you publish in Visual Studio, this code will find every `.js` and `.css` file in your source, and create a minified copy using the extension `.jsMIN` and `.cssMIN`. It will ignore files that are already minified. Then it will copy these minified files to the deployment folder, using the original file names.

Voilà! You just published minified JS/CSS files, while your original files stay intact on your development environment.

Optional:
Want Ajax Minifier to be packaged with your project? From the Ajax Minifier install folder, you can move `AjaxMin.dll` and `AjaxMinTask.dll` directly into your source directory. I put them in my `App_Data` folder. Once they're somewhere in your source, in Visual Studio right-click them, select `Include in Project`, and also change their `Build Action` property to `None`.

Then in the code I included above, change
`<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\Microsoft Ajax Minifier\ajaxmin.tasks" />`
to
`<UsingTask TaskName="AjaxMin" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\App_Data\AjaxMinTask.dll" />`
Done.

A troubleshooting tip:
My main code above executes `AfterBuild` and only when the configuration is `Release`. That's so it will only run during a publish. If your configuration is named something else, or you want it to run in other circumstances, modify the code as needed.

Comment: link is dead now

Answer (score 1):

A nice tool can be downloaded from Visual studio Marketplace.

[Bundler & Minifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier)